# Disable WARN logging from AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Below exception handler that is common for all my controllers, is working fine except that I need to disable the WARN log from `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` class after processing the exception. Using Spring Web MVC 5.x version.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class AllExceptionHandler{
    @ExceptionHandler(SomeCustomException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void exceptionHandler() {
    }
}
```

This is the log that is generated which I'm trying to avoid:

> 02-20-2019 15:22:54,896  WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-1] (AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:140) - Resolved [com.rasa.rrt.ste.controller.SomeCustomException]

I'm not using Spring Boot.

Tried to extend the above `AllExceptionHandler` class with  `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` and call `warnLogCategory(null)` in the `AllExceptionHandler` constructor, but it throws `NullPointerException`.

Also, I see on Google to set this property `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=false` to disable warning, but not sure where/how to set it.

Comment: Might not be what you are looking for exactly, an alternative option could be: in your logging configuration, you could add an entry for AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver then set the level to DEBUG. Note that it would get rid of all your WARN logs for that class not just the one specific that you don't want

Comment: @lorraine Our application uses log4j2, but Spring uses some other logging I guess, Spring is not taking the log configuration from our log4j2.xml file.

Comment: You can override libraries log level if I'm not wrong, just put an entry on your log config file.  We do it for hibernate if when we want to examine its execution by adding entry on our log config file using the hibernate class and specify level.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=false` as a possible solution:

> Also, I see on google to set this property "spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=false" to disable warning, but not sure where/how to set it.

The `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception` property is a [Spring Boot property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception), and would be set using standard Spring Boot [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) mechanisms.  Enabling the property causes Spring Boot to configure `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans to log exceptions when they otherwise wouldn't.

> Whether to enable warn logging of exceptions resolved by a "HandlerExceptionResolver", except for "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver".

Since you've stated you're not using Spring Boot, this property is not applicable to your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable this warning log in your logback configuration,
by specifying in my case in 'logback-spring.groovy' following line

```
logger("org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver", ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

When introducing spring-boot-devtools in Spring Boot, the log-resolved-exception will be automatically enabled. To disable it, you need to set `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception: false` in the profile file. In the production environment where devtools does not exist, you don’t need to worry about this issue.